# Asp.net 4.8 MVC + Vite + Svelte + HMR?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, svelte, vite

I have a legacy application built in ASP.NET 4.8 MVC.
I would like to start building some client side features in Svelte - having svelte components rendering inside razor views. This I have working. I can render a svelte component anywhere in the razor page.
However vite has some problem (im guessing with HMR?), and it keeps refreshing the razor page (https://localhost:44300/somefeature) every few seconds.

**Environment**

asp.net 4.8 mvc loads to https://localhost:44300/
vite is loading on http://localhost:3000/

Here is what i have so far. I ran npm init vite@latest -> selected svelte + svelte TS

**vite.config.js**

```html
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      compilerOptions: {
        customElement: true,
      }
    })
  ],
  build:{
    // generate manifest.json in outDir
    manifest: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      // overwrite default .html entry
      input: '/src/main.ts'
    }
  }
})
```

Then i followed the instructions here https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html and added this to the razor page:

```
@Html.Raw("<script type='module' src='http://localhost:3000/@vite/client'></script>")
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:3000/src/main.ts"></script>
```

(Note - had to use Html.Raw because it wouldnt let me escape the @ correctly - even with @@)
At this point it is rendering my Svelte component perfectly.
The issue however is that vite is now reloading my page every 2 seconds or so - im guessing because HMR is no longer working correctly as the console just says: [vite] connecting...

Can anyone point me in a direction either to get HMR working whilst using another Backend server? For some reason it works in asp.net core, but not so in ASP.NET 4.8. Any observations to help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Ok i got it working. Here is my vite.config.js. Pay special attention to the
input, outDir and server nodes, and adjust them to your scenario. The proxy is important, you can either set it to your https or http mvc endpoint and port that asp.net spins up for you.

Here is the config:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    svelte()
  ],
  build:{
    // generate manifest.json in outDir
    manifest: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      // overwrite default .html entry
      input: 'Scripts/svelte/app.js',
    },
    outDir: 'Scripts/svelte/dist'
  },
  server: {
    proxy:{
      '*' : {
        target: 'http://localhost:26688',
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    },
    hmr: {
      protocol: 'ws'
    }
  }
})
```

Its pretty cool - you get instant HMR of any svelte component inside a razor page without losing any razor state.

Comment: It's working perfectly in the development, however, I could not resolve 'assets' folder for the production (if published as asp.net application)

Answer (score 3):

THANK YOU!!!! This is exactly what I was looking for to include my react code in my old Asp.Net 4.8 site with hot module reload!

For other's the thing I had to include in my cshtml to make the react stuff load properly was:

```
<script type="module">
        import RefreshRuntime from "http://localhost:9999/@@react-refresh"
        RefreshRuntime.injectIntoGlobalHook(window)
        window.$RefreshReg$ = () => {}
        window.$RefreshSig$ = () => (type) => type
        window.__vite_plugin_react_preamble_installed__ = true
 </script>
```

If you don't include this you get an error saying '@vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble'.

I am hosting the development site in IIS locally so to serve up the local files, I just created a /src folder off of the root or my application pointing to the src in my react directory and it worked beautifullly!!

Comment: What did you resolve svg issues in development environment?